# join two tables in R using Names from both tables

Tags: r, sqldf, fuzzyjoin

Hi guys I know there are few questions related to joining tables in R, I tried most of them but they didn't work, in my case, I have two tables first one (A) has two columns (`Id` and `company_name`), 70,000 rows, and the second one (B) has `company_name`, `registration number` .....etc with 10,000,000 rows.

I want to join them to get the `registration number` for all the companies in A.

*hint*, I tried to merge, `inner join` using `sqldf`,`fuzzyjoin` and `vlookup` in excel but it didn't return all the record in A.

Comment: `merge(A, B, "company_name", all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give an answer without any example code or data but let me try.

I can see three possible problems here.

1: Do you want to have all entries from A in your result set? even if there were no match from B? then you should use a left outer join.
for example with merge you should have `merge(A,B,by="company_name",all.x = TRUE)`

2: As I can see you want to join on company_name, is the class character in both A and B? sometimes it is converted for some reason to factor when you read in the file. convert them to character with `A$company_name = as.character(A$company_name)` and do the same for B

3: maybe there are extra characters in the names (like whitespaces) or special characters. If it's only that you can remove them and do the merging after that. use this: `gsub('[^[:alnum:]]','',tolower(iconv(A$company_name, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')))`. This will make sure you get rid off all unwanted stuff.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I think I should have made more clear my fault, yes I want entries from A because I am 100% sure that all the companies in A are in B. I have converted both company_name columns into Characters and tried merge function, join using SQLDF and  fuzzyjoin package

Comment: Can you present an example where it should work but it's not? that way it will be much easier to find a solution

Comment: this is one of the companies in A One Stop Shop and its the same in B One Stop Shop
but when I join both tables I got Null

Comment: str(B$CompanyName)
 chr [1:1048575] "LTD" "BIG IMPACT GRAPHICS LIMITED" "NNOV8 LIMITED" "NSPIRED LTD" "NVERTD DESIGNS LIMITED" "OBAC LIMITED" ...
> str(A$name)
 chr [1:57308] "Cantalis Ltd" "One Stop Shop" "EJ FINANCIAL LIMITED" "Mr A J Jones & Mrs S Al-Shamma" ...

Comment: I don't see _One Stop Shop_ in B, but! for me it looks like everything in B is uppercase but not in A. use tolower() for `company_name` in both tables

Answer (score 0):

R

```
merge(table_a, table_b, by = "company_name", all.x = TRUE)
```

Excel

> A: Id from table1 .
>   B: company_name from table1 .
>   C: company_name from table2 .
>   D: registration_number from table2 .

Use this formula in any other column to get registration_number

```
Vlookup(B2, $C$2:$D$10000001, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: I have tried both cases but before and the didn't work

Comment: Did you check for case mismatch and column datatypes mismatch in R?

Comment: yes I did both columns are characters type

Comment: str(B$CompanyName)
 chr [1:1048575] "LTD" "BIG IMPACT GRAPHICS LIMITED" "NNOV8 LIMITED" "NSPIRED LTD" "NVERTD DESIGNS LIMITED" "OBAC LIMITED" ...
> str(A$name)
 chr [1:57308] "Cantalis Ltd" "One Stop Shop" "EJ FINANCIAL LIMITED" "Mr A J Jones & Mrs S Al-Shamma" ...